# Hide Simple Social Buttons plugin output in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working in a custom post type and now I need to hide the output generated by [Simple Social Buttons](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-social-buttons/) plugin. I tried this code: `remove_filter('the_content', 'plugin_action_links', 100);` in `single-magazine_post_type.php` just below `get_header()` but didn't work. Any advice?

PS: Exists any plugin that can work on this without the need to touch code all the time?

Comment: Please note, there are a couple of bugs in this plugin. You should take this up with the author as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in simple social plugin called `insert_buttons` in `simple-social-buttons/simple-social-buttons.php`. This function puts social buttons to your content. You can make an exception there like;

```
function insert_buttons($content) {
    global $post;
    if ( !empty( $post ) ) {
        if ( get_post_type( $post ) == "your_post_type") {
            return $content;   
        }
    }
   ......
}
```

**Edit:** How to do that?

**1)** Open plugin editor in admin panel

[image]

**2)** Select `Simple Social Buttons` from the list

[image]

**3)** Select `buttons/simple-social-buttons.php` from list

[image]

**4)** Update `insert_buttons` function as I mentioned above

[image]

Comment: @ReynierPM I have realised that plugin hooks are not stable for doing your requirement. I have ppropose another solution. See my updated answer

Comment: Sorry @huseyin-babal I'm not a WP expert so I need to ask what that functions does? I suppose this should be on `functions.php` in my theme but what then? Also since Pieter comment I decide to move to another plugin, [this one](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/) in this case but still not working to hide in the custom post type and I can't find a way to do this

Comment: @ReynierPM It is simple to apply my answer to your case. If you can use first plugin you provided in your question, you need to do following steps. Go to plugins editor on admin panel And select Simple Social Buttons on right top on page. Select `buttons/simple-social-buttons.php` from the list. Find the function with name `insert_buttons` and update starting point of that function like in my answer

Comment: @ReynierPM I have added step by step information. See updated answer

Comment: I wouldn't edit plugin's code. Did it once and I made the plugin un-updatable. Or worse, you forget about it and lose your edits on plugin update.